# Runtime Err 438 for Outlook.Application.Recipients.Add()

Tags: ms-access, outlook, vba6

ISSUE: Outlook Automation fails at [Outlook Application].Recipients.Add ("Jon Grande")

Error message:

> Runtime Error 438: "Object does not support this property or method.

MS example: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/Outlook.Recipients

Line that fails: `Set MailRecip = App.Recipients.Add("Jon Grande")`

```vb
Private Sub cmdEmail_Contact_Click()
   
    Call TestOutlookIsOpen                'AUTHOR: Ron Debruin> https://www.rondebruin.nl/win/s1/outlook/openclose.htm
    Call GetAppExePath("msaccess.exe")    'AUTHOR:  Daniel Pineault, CARDA Consultants Inc.
    ' IsAppRunning ("Outlook.Application")    'https://www.devhut.net/createobjectoutlook-application-does-not-work-now-what/
    ' GetAppExePath("firefox.exe")            'AUTHOR:  Daniel Pineault, CARDA Consultants Inc.
    ' GetAppExePath ("outlook.exe")           'AUTHOR:  Daniel Pineault, CARDA Consultants Inc.
    
   
    Dim App                   As Object    'Outlook.Application
    Dim Mail                  As Object    'Outlook.MailItem
    Dim MailRecip             As Object    'Outlook.Recipient
    Const olMailItem = 0

    Set App = CreateObject("Outlook.application")
   
    Set Mail = OutlookApp()  '<<<<<<<<<<< See Sub Macro MyMacroThatUseOutlook in TestTheCode Module

    
    With Mail
         
        Set MailRecip = App.Recipients.Add("Jon Grande")
        
         **Set MailRecip = App.Recipients.Add("Jon Grande")**
         Set MailRecip = App.Recipients.Add("Graham Smithwick@yahoo.com")
        
        MailRecip.Type = 1    'Designates the above is TO recipients
        .Subject = "5105088005@tmomail.net"
        .Body = "<a href='tel:19254511573'> To Call CaolePepe (925-451-1573)</a> "

        For Each MailRecip In .Recipients
            If Not MailRecip.Resolve Then
                Mail.Display
            End If
        Next

        .Send    'this sends the mail
    End With

    Set MailRecip = Nothing
    Set Mail = Nothing
    Set App = Nothing
End Sub
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to add recipients to the `Application` object, which makes no sense.
Try the updated code below. (off the top of my head):

```
Call TestOutlookIsOpen                'AUTHOR: Ron Debruin> https://www.rondebruin.nl/win/s1/outlook/openclose.htm
Call GetAppExePath("msaccess.exe")    'AUTHOR:  Daniel Pineault, CARDA Consultants Inc.
' IsAppRunning ("Outlook.Application")    'https://www.devhut.net/createobjectoutlook-application-does-not-work-now-what/
' GetAppExePath("firefox.exe")            'AUTHOR:  Daniel Pineault, CARDA Consultants Inc.
' GetAppExePath ("outlook.exe")           'AUTHOR:  Daniel Pineault, CARDA Consultants Inc.

Dim App                   As Object    'Outlook.Application
Dim Mail                  As Object    'Outlook.MailItem
Dim MailRecip             As Object    'Outlook.Recipient
Const olMailItem = 0

Set App = CreateObject("Outlook.application")

Set Mail = App.CreateItem(0)
With Mail
    Set MailRecip = .Recipients.Add("Jon Grande")
    Set MailRecip = .Recipients.Add("Graham Smithwick@yahoo.com")
    MailRecip.Type = 1    'Designates the above is TO recipients
    .Subject = "5105088005@tmomail.net"
    .Body = "<a href='tel:19254511573'> To Call CaolePepe (925-451-1573)</a> "
    For Each MailRecip In .Recipients
        If Not MailRecip.Resolve Then
            Mail.Display
        End If
    Next
    .Send    'this sends the mail
End With

Set MailRecip = Nothing
Set Mail = Nothing
Set App = Nothing
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you need to use the `mail` object instead of `App` to be able to call the `Recipients` property:

```
With Mail
     
    Set MailRecip = .Recipients.Add("Jon Grande")
    
     **Set MailRecip = .Recipients.Add("Jon Grande")**
     Set MailRecip = .Recipients.Add("Graham Smithwick@yahoo.com")
    
    MailRecip.Type = 1    'Designates the above is TO recipients
    .Subject = "5105088005@tmomail.net"
    .Body = "<a href='tel:19254511573'> To Call CaolePepe (925-451-1573)</a> "

    If Not myRecipients.ResolveAll Then 
       Mail.Display
    End If  

    .Send    'this sends the mail
End With
```

Also there is no need to iterate over all `Recipients` in the code and checking the `Resolve` method call results:

```
 For Each MailRecip In .Recipients
        If Not MailRecip.Resolve Then
            Mail.Display
        End If
    Next
```

Instead, you could use the [Recipients.ResolveAll](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.recipients.resolveall) method which attempts to resolve all the `Recipient` objects in the `Recipients` collection against the Address Book.

Read more about that in the [How To: Fill TO,CC and BCC fields in Outlook programmatically](https://www.add-in-express.com/creating-addins-blog/2011/09/08/outlook-fill-recipients-programmatically/) article.

Comment: Thanks, Eugene, I missed the obvious.  I applied the correction to Set .Receipients to the Mail Object instead of the App Object, but still missing something, as I am getting the same Err.

Answer (score 0):

**Got it!**

```
 Set App = CreateObject("Outlook.application")
Dim msgRecipient As String
msgRecipient = "****************@gmail.comt"                                     
Dim oMail As Object                                                         
Set oMail = App.CreateItem(0)
Set MailRecip = oMail.Recipients.Add(msgRecipient)
With oMail
        Set MailRecips = oMail.Recipients
        MailRecip.Type = 1    'Designates the above is TO recipients
        .Subject = Me.[Company]
        .Body = "<a href='tel:1925***-****'> To Call(925-***-*****)</a> "
    If Not MailRecips.ResolveAll Then   
        oMail.Display
    End If
    .Send
    'MailRecip.send    'this sends the mail
End With
Set MailRecip = Nothing
Set oMail = Nothing
Set App = Nothing
```